# Git for-each-ref showing deleted branches

Tags: git, git-bash

Using this to list all our branches:
`git for-each-ref --sort='-committerdate' refs/remotes --format='"%(refname)",%(committerdate:iso),"%(authorname)"' > branches.csv`

Now, I go in and delete a lot of stale branches...Run the command again and the deleted branches are STILL showing.

Why? How can I make it omit the deleted branches?

Comment: You are listing remote tracking branches. Did you remove the branches from the remote repositories, and then `git fetch --prune $remote` to delete the tracked branches locally as well?

Comment: Ah, did a fetch but not prune. Let me try that.

Comment: Post as answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted command lists *remote-tracking branches*. These are local copies of the branches available on the remote site.

After you delete the branches from the remote site, the local copies must be removed explicitly with

```
git fetch --prune $remote
```